# Fastest way to fread/process "JSON-like" column in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

Here's some sample data I'm working with. `DT_IN` contains the input format of the data and `DT_OUT` contains the form that I would like to use. What's the best way to go from `DT_IN` to `DT_OUT`?

I've tried `strsplit`, but did not manage to order the splits to `rbind` them in the corresponding order. Am open to solutions, maybe `Rcpp` could help?

```
library(data.table)
DT_IN <- data.table(
  user_id = c(1L, 20L, 4L, 6L, 9L), 
  latitude = c(-41.3103218, -40.8307381, -37.3932037, -42.7178726, -45.0156822), 
  longitude = c(174.824554, 172.793106, 175.840637, 170.965454, 168.731186), 
  parameters = c(
    "{\"\"network\"\"=>\"\"Telecom NZ\"\", \"\"accuracy\"\"=>28.659999847412, \"\"internet\"\"=>\"\"4G\"\", \"\"location_age\"\"=>1}", 
    "{\"\"location_age\"\"=>716}", "{\"\"location_age\"\"=>851}", "{\"\"accuracy\"\"=>14, \"\"location_age\"\"=>1}", 
    "{\"\"network\"\"=>\"\"VodafoneNZ\"\", \"\"accuracy\"\"=>29, \"\"internet\"\"=>\"\"3G\"\", \"\"location_age\"\"=>31}"
  )
)
> DT_IN
   user_id  latitude longitude                                                                                              parameters
1:       1 -41.31032  174.8246 {""network""=>""Telecom NZ"", ""accuracy""=>28.659999847412, ""internet""=>""4G"", ""location_age""=>1}
2:      20 -40.83074  172.7931                                                                                 {""location_age""=>716}
3:       4 -37.39320  175.8406                                                                                 {""location_age""=>851}
4:       6 -42.71787  170.9655                                                                 {""accuracy""=>14, ""location_age""=>1}
5:       9 -45.01568  168.7312             {""network""=>""VodafoneNZ"", ""accuracy""=>29, ""internet""=>""3G"", ""location_age""=>31}
DT_OUT <- data.table(
  user_id = c(1L, 20L, 4L, 6L, 9L), 
  latitude = c(-41.3103218, -40.8307381, -37.3932037, -42.7178726, -45.0156822), 
  longitude = c(174.824554, 172.793106, 175.840637, 170.965454, 168.731186), 
  network = c('Telecom NZ', NA, NA, NA, 'VodafoneNZ'), 
  accuracy = c(28.659999847412, NA, NA, 14, 29), 
  internet = c('4G', NA, NA, NA, '3G'), 
  location_age = c(1, 716, 851, 1, 31)
)
> DT_OUT
   user_id  latitude longitude    network accuracy internet location_age
1:       1 -41.31032  174.8246 Telecom NZ    28.66       4G            1
2:      20 -40.83074  172.7931       <NA>       NA     <NA>          716
3:       4 -37.39320  175.8406       <NA>       NA     <NA>          851
4:       6 -42.71787  170.9655       <NA>    14.00     <NA>            1
5:       9 -45.01568  168.7312 VodafoneNZ    29.00       3G           31
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `jsonlite` package ...

```
# Convert json like strings to json.
DT_IN[, parameters := gsub("\"\"", "\"", parameters)]
DT_IN[, parameters := gsub("=>", ":", parameters)]

# Stream_in the json and cbind it to existing data.
DT_IN <- cbind(DT_IN, jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(DT_IN$parameters)))

# Remove `parameters`
DT_IN[, parameters := NULL]

DT_IN
#    user_id  latitude longitude    network accuracy internet location_age
# 1:       1 -41.31032  174.8246 Telecom NZ    28.66       4G            1
# 2:      20 -40.83074  172.7931       <NA>       NA     <NA>          716
# 3:       4 -37.39320  175.8406       <NA>       NA     <NA>          851
# 4:       6 -42.71787  170.9655       <NA>    14.00     <NA>            1
# 5:       9 -45.01568  168.7312 VodafoneNZ    29.00       3G           31
```